# how do i open a local aspx file in xcode?

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, objective-c, xcode

I'd like to open local MAIN.aspx.

I was trying to open local png file, it's opened.

and html, too.

BUT MAIN.aspx is not opened!

my resources

```
/web

-> MAIN.aspx
-> MAIN.aspx.cs
-> MAIN.js
-> Web.config
-> Web.Debug.config
-> close.png
```

Why not open local MAIN.aspx?
What should I do to open the file?

This is my Code:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MAIN" ofType@"aspx"];
NSLog(@"path %@",path);
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[_myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

This is NSLog (MAIN.aspx) :

```
file:///Users/lee/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/BE6F01B5-8E92-44C6-82C7-C70C58FC6EDC/WebViewTest.app/MAIN.aspx
```

**Solved! Because asp.net is server page..
iphone is not server.
Thanks.**

Comment: Can you show the error that you are getting ? That might help to know whats stopping it from opening.

Comment: Can you confirm if your `NSURL *url` is not `nil`?

Comment: There's a : missing from your example before @"aspx". Are you sure you've included MAIN.aspx to be copied to the application bundle?

Comment: Path is all right! Nslog was display. But Webpage wasn't!

Comment: bundle contain MAIN.aspx!  sorry to late..T.T

Comment: no error.. no warning! Just be not opened